# ASP.NET core 3.1 rendering a form with Incorrect values for Input fields on GET request

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am building a small web application where I am using `Identity` for Authentication and Authorization of users of my website. The problem I am currently facing is that when I go to `Register` page (make a `GET` request), values for `Email` and `Password` are already filled (which is already very weird). First of all I have no idea from where those values are coming from and secondly I have tried to use `ModelState.Clear()` in the `OnGetAsync()`. But it still does not works. Every time I load the page out of all the form fields `Email` and `Password` are prefilled. I would add some screenshots so you guys could see whats going on.

Here is `Input` model in my `Register.cshtml.cs` which is used in my `Register.cshtml`

```
public class InputModel
        {
            [MaxLength(15)]
            [Display(Name = "First Name")]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
            [MaxLength(15)]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string City { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string State { get; set; }
            [Required]
            public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
            [Required]
            [EmailAddress]
            [Display(Name = "Email")]
            public string Email { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} and at max {1} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Password")]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
            [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
            public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        }
```

Below is the `OnGetAsync()` in `Register.cshtml.cs`

```
public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();
            ModelState.Clear();
        }
```

Below is `Register.cshtml`

```
@page
@model RegisterModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Register";
}

<h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
            <h4>Create a new account.</h4>
            <hr />
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.FirstName"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Input.FirstName" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Input.FirstName"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.LastName"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Input.LastName" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Input.LastName"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.City"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Input.City"/>
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Input.City"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.State"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Input.State"/>
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Input.State"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber"></label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" asp-for="Input.PhoneNumber" />
                <span class="text-danger" asp-validation-for="Input.PhoneNumber"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            <p>Already have an account? Click <a asp-page="Login" asp-area="Identity">Here</a> to login</p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

**EDIT**
When I delete the `Email` and `Password` `div`(s) from the `Register.cshtml` page, the values are then displayed into `PhoneNumber` and `ConfirmPassword` input tags.
[image: As you can see Email and Password fields are prefilled with incorrect data]

Comment: Basically this is your browser assuming the page is a login form and it populates the "remembered" login information. Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23646953/stop-browser-from-auto-filling-the-form-username-and-password-fields

Comment: Did you try `autocomplete="off"`? Whether the input box value is the other website form's value, or the current website?

Comment: @Karney. I did try `autocomplete=off` but it still shows me the values the input fields..

Comment: @Usman_Codes._., will it happen in other browsers? The browser could have opened the auto-filled in setting. `ModelState.Clear()` can clear the `[BindProperty]` value, but it could not clear the browser's form value.

Comment: Well I cleared the passwords and emails that were saved during development on the `localhost` and now the values are not being showed up.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone in the future facing this problem, there is likely nothing wrong with your code but you might need to clear the already saved `passwords` and `usernames` by the `localhost` in the browser (if you have any). You can also try changing the `port` your app is running on because it is possible that some previous project running on the same port as your current project has saved something (likely a `username` or `password`) in the browser which is conflicting with you current application.