# Base64 encoded OpenType font-face using data URI

Tags: html, css, base64, font-face

I want to add a `base64 encoded` OpenType font as a data URI in font-face.

I have this so far:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'test';
    src: url(data:font/otf;base64,
        // Base64 string here ...
    ) format('opentype');
}
```

But I believe it does not include the font correctly to my style.

Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: Use `'`s to wrap the values please. What browser are you using?

Comment: i tried that and also google chrome

Comment: Oh yeah, it is `font/opentype` not `otf`.

Comment: still doesnt work :(

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Data URIs are always of this format:

```
data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>
```

The very first part of every [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) is the `media-type`, which in the case of an `Open Type` font is:

```
font/opentype
```

So, you may use it like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: test;
    src: url(data:font/opentype; base64, [base64 string here]);
}
```

Replacing

```
[base64 string here]
```

with the exact copy-pasted version of your base-64 encoded string.

**Notes**

Please note that:

- you should use `font/opentype` for the `data`, not `otf`.
- you should copy-paste the exact base-64 encode string, without any changes like added spaces, etc (I believe there are some spaces in it)

**Online Encoding Tool**

You may use [this](http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/Base64Encode/) tool, to convert your font file to the encoded string.

Comment: do the ". . ." matter?

Comment: just replace the `// Base64 string here ...` with the copy-pasted version of your base-64 encoded string

Comment: are all fonts base64 compatible?

Comment: Yes. base64 has nothing to do with file type. it is just an encoding method, which reads the file contents and encode it as an string. Please read the answer carefully and I am sure you will put it to work

Comment: @Pmpr What is the equivalent for this to support lower versions of IE like IE8? Because AFAIK, base64 is supported from IE10 and up. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Is there an example you could provide, such that we copy what's between `<style>` and `</style>` ? (I have coped a number from other sites like [here](http://stephenscaff.com/articles/2013/09/font-face-and-base64-data-uri/) but without successfully getting it to work

Answer (score 16):

Although not asked, I'm sure that someone will come here looking for the woff2 solution and will have the same issues I had. Upload the file using this site: https://base64.guru/converter/encode/file Ensure you use the option "Data URI". Replace the url() value with the code from the site.

For the CSS I had to use the following code:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MYFONT'; /*This is what your font will be named*/
    src: local('MYFONT'), /* It will check the machine for a font matching this name, if it exists it will use this. Not needed when your are writing the woff2 file since you already sending all the data. */
         url('data:@file/octet-stream;base64,d09GMgABAAAAAK6kABIAAAABgQgAAK47AAA=') /*This is the base64 code copy pasted from the site*/
         format('woff2'); /*This ensures the browser treats it as a WOFF2 file. Notice there is no comma after the url() */
}
```

To get your custom font to work you need to specify it:

```
<div style="font-family: MYFONT">
    My new font
</div>
```

The actual base64 code I have posted does not work. The woff2 file i was using is 50kb and didn't want page after page of base64 code.

Comment: You use data:@file and not data:font?