# Issue loading custom fonts inside Apple's WebKit webView

Tags: html, ios, swift, objective-c, webkit

I am currently working on migrating from UIWebView to the supported WKWebView through my app. Everything loads fine except one thing - the font.

Even though my html (which I am loading) hasn't changed at all, in the app's version which utilizes UIWebView the custom font does load up. On the other hand, in the app that uses WKWebView everything loads *but* with with a default font and not the custom font which I am loading.

Is there a known issue regarding this functionality in WebKit??

**EDIT:**
After changing the source URL the font does load. But the font weight does not change from variable to variable, as you can see in the HTML code added below.

Same code I'm using both in my UIWebView app and WKWebView app:

```
NSString *strTemplateHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head>%@<style>%@</style><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"></head><body style=''>%@</body></html>",[self getAdsScript], styles, self.firstPartArticleContent];

[self.articleWebView loadHTMLString:strTemplateHTML baseURL:NSBundle.mainBundle.bundleURL];
```

The HTML:

```
body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
font-family:'Heebo';
font-size:%ldpx !important;
direction: rtl;
width: 100%%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Heebo';
  font-style: normal;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/heebo/v12/NGS6v5_NC0k9P9H0TbFhsqMA6aw.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0590-05FF, U+20AA, U+25CC, U+FB1D-FB4F;
}
img {
    max-width:100%%;
    max-height: none;
    height:auto;
    width:100%%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
iframe {
    max-width: 100%%;
    max-height: none;
    width: 100%%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
a{
    color: #5da1c9;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.OUTBRAIN a {
    white-space: initial; 
} 
.articlelink {
    color: #32AE7B;
    font-size:%ldpx;
    font-family:'Heebo';
    font-weight:700;
}
.streamerPositive {
    color:#34eb7a;
    font-family:'Heebo';
    font-weight:500;
}
.streamerNeutral {
    color:#9FA6A1;
    font-family:'Heebo';
    font-weight:500;
}
.streamerNegative {
    color:#d41717;
    font-family:'Heebo';
    font-weight:500;
};
```

Comment: Can you update post with HTML file together with font? (random text)

Comment: When a font should be loaded how will the URL look like when there is a sandboxed folder name of the App space that can and will change anytime you launch the app? So your `styles` NSString is of interest and how you serve the font's url from the apps resource folder. Because the baseURL here is just for the HTML not for the fonts url as string.. one possible workaround is to serve base64 data for the [font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120217/base64-encoded-opentype-font-face-using-data-uri). Also the resource real folder structure is of interest.