# Loading dynamically generated font files in web browser JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, webfonts

I am generating font data files (WOFF2) in JavaScript. Is it possible to load these files from JavaScript-generated binary data within the web browser itself, or do I need to host the files somewhere first to make them available to the browser and its CSS?

Comment: You can encode the font type in base64 .. look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120217/base64-encoded-opentype-font-face-using-data-uri

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as you can convert it to an acceptable [data URI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "<name of your font>";
  src: url("data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,<font data as base64>") format("woff2");
}

.custom-font {
  font-family: "<name of your font>";
}
```