# A font with all the characters the same

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm looking for a font which displays a  or a * for every character, in the same way. A totally unreadable font.

Despite my efforts I couldn't find one on the internet. Is there a system font like this ? Or do you know one ?

Comment: Could you explain your reasons for this? Maybe there is a better solution :)

Comment: My website has a user login system that works a really special way. The user uses <SELECT> boxes to pick a letter and to compose his login. I made a JS function that changes the font of the input whenever the user has chosen a letter. Now I just need a font that is totally unreadable.

Comment: Isn't it what you're looking for ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16258194/imitate-a-password-type-input-while-using-a-contenteditable-div

Comment: Not really. I need this kind of font and I'm surprised it doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @Rackover The font named _AlphaShapes square_ looks to do what you want, but only for the capital letters.

Comment: As you already use JS, catch the key event and replace any character with a star `*`

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte This doesn't work, as the squares get replaced with the default font because they are not really square-chars, more like no-chars-at-all.

Comment: @LGSon How do I replace the character with another without changing the input "value" ?

Comment: For a standard `input` field you set its type to `password`, for any other element you add the entered value in a hidden `input` field and the star `*` in the visual one

Comment: I would go crazy to have to use a login like that, still, if you put an input and a select element on top of each other, you can hide the select when a value is chosen, pass its selected value to the `input` field, which have the `password` type

Comment: Nvm, I ended with making the background color the same color than the font. That's cheap, but it works.

Comment: @Rackover if it's 'cheap', is it still secure?

Comment: This sounds like a terrible login system, but to answer the question: just make your yourself. Use FontForge, which is free, and drop in the shape you need, then generate the WOFF. It's trivially easy.

Comment: Terrible login system - but a fun prank if you change someone's system font to it ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I doubt that such a font exists, an alternative could be to do your own `select`. Using the `data-*` attribute provided by [HTML5](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp), you can attach any additional information to any element. So, you can develop a select that would display the character you want (e.g. `*`) but set `data-something` to the correct value. Then, when the user press on a button or so, you can call a function to iterate through your personal selects and read the `data-something` from them to compute the data the user entered.

Here is a minimal example of such a code : https://jsfiddle.net/w0za8ut6/2/

Comment: Some banks here in the UK use this approach for people to enter some letters from a pre-selected passphrase when logging in online. I would trust if the banks use it that this method should be suitable for OP's needs.

Comment: a font like this is trivially created.

Answer (score 3):

The Google font [**Flow Block**](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Flow+Block?query=block) should come closest to your requirements, however spaces are still spaces

Answer (score 0):

Make one. Just fire up [FontForge](https://fontforge.github.io), the authoritative open source font editor of choice, and make a font with your desired glyph pasted into every letter box that you need supported, or you can craft a [cmap 13](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/opentype/spec/cmap#format-13-many-to-one-range-mappings) font with a single glyph but defined as used for the entire code range, like Adobe's "Blank" font.

Generate your font, pick "web open font" format to make it a WOFF2 instead of a system font like ttf/otf, and done. You can now load it with an `@font-face` rule.

That said, what you want to do sounds like a weird hack that doesn't actually make passwords any more or less secure, but that's your decision.

The font part at least is almost trivially easy.