# How to prevent a browser from storing passwords

Tags: html, security, browser

I need to stop browsers from storing the username & password values, because I'm working on a web application which contains more secure data. My client asked me to do this.

I tried the `autocomplete="off"` attribute in the HTML form and password fields. But it is not working in the latest browsers like Chrome 55, Firefox 38+, Internet Explorer 11, etc.

What is the best solution for this?

Comment: I have a similar situation - an internal web application with a support-tech-only area where the password unlocks unsafe features of the application. Allowing the end user access to this would be very bad, so yes, there are valid situations where you do not want passwords to be saved. Still looking for a working answer, by the way.

Comment: One use case is where users share a computer, but need to log in as individuals into a webapp.

Comment: My solution is a bit of a hack, but I used JS to clear the field.

Comment: I really don't recommend people do this in 2020 unless you have a very special situation. This makes security worse. Users should be using a unique password for every different service they use.  Of course there's no way remember so many unique and unrelated passwords, so users need use a password manger to do this.  All the big browsers have ones built in and there's lots of 3rd party options. Besides some special case exceptions, blocking password mangers will likely end up hurting your security more than helping it.

Comment: https://github.com/noppa/text-security

Comment: @Chris - its precisely the 'special case exceptions' why there really should be a proper way of doing this. Those rare cases where the whole point is to confirm the user is still the same user, or when they are changing the password and you know (as a developer) that the saved value MUST be wrong.

Comment: @Morvael for users following best practices and using a password manager, I don't see why disabling autocomplete would confirm they're the same user? At least when the prompt is asking for my current password. But I totally agree there are situations when you want to avoid autofill, I just think they're quite rare. Like when changing a password you don't want the new password field to be autocompleted with the old one. (but I _think_ if you just set the input field's name to something like "new_password", a good password manager, like Chrome or 1P, will know not to autofill the old password)

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Thank you for giving a reply to me. I followed the below link

[Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality/37292424#37292424)

I resolved the issue by just adding `readonly` & `onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"` attributes besides `autocomplete="off"` to the inputs as shown below.

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" autocomplete="off" readonly 
onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" >

<input type="password" name="Password" autocomplete="off" readonly 
onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');" >
```

This is working fine for me.

Comment: `autocomplete` attribute is no longer supported by the browsers

Comment: tried this, doesn't work also esp firefox dev edition

Comment: My solution is a bit of a hack, but I used JS to clear the field.

Comment: on my login page (mvc project) I added: 
onfocus ="this.removeAttribute('readonly');",
onfocusout ="this.setAttribute('readonly','readonly');"
and it works as a charm! even in FireFox ‏67.0.4 ‏(64 bits)!
thank you!

Comment: in firefox browser version 84.0b8 (64-bit) does not work.

Comment: This method broke the keyboard on iOS devices. 
The keyboard wasn't showing on Iphones.

Answer (score 40):

Trying to prevent the browser from storing passwords is not a recommended thing to do. There *are* some workarounds that can do it, but modern browsers do not provide this feature out-of-the-box and for good reason. Modern browsers store passwords in password managers in order to enable users to use stronger passwords than they would usually.

As explained by [MDN: How to Turn Off Form Autocompletion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#The_autocomplete_attribute_and_login_fields):

> Modern browsers implement integrated password management: when the user enters a username and password for a site, the browser offers to remember it for the user. When the user visits the site again, the browser autofills the login fields with the stored values.
>
> Additionally, the browser enables the user to choose a master password that the browser will use to encrypt stored login details.
>
> Even without a master password, **in-browser password management is generally seen as a net gain for security**. Since users do not have to remember passwords that the browser stores for them, they are able to choose stronger passwords than they would otherwise.
>
> For this reason, **many modern browsers do not support `autocomplete="off"`** for login fields:
>
> - If a site sets `autocomplete="off"` for a form, and the form includes username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits the page.
> - If a site sets `autocomplete="off"` for username and password input fields, then the browser will still offer to remember this login, and if the user agrees, the browser will autofill those fields the next time the user visits the page.
>
> **This is the behavior in Firefox (since version 38), Google Chrome (since 34), and Internet Explorer (since version 11).**
>
> If an author would like to prevent the autofilling of password fields in user management pages where a user can specify a new password for someone other than themself, `autocomplete="new-password"` should be specified, though support for this has not been implemented in all browsers yet.

Comment: It is so, so trivially easy to reveal a password in a browser.  Just open developer tools, change the input type from password to text, and voila!  There it is.

Comment: There are use cases where password manager makes no sense. Such as changing a password. autocomplete="new-password" does not work for me as at Firefox 55.0.3 x64

Comment: Thanks, worked for me and this is very simple. I am use Chome Version 64.0.3282.186 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: In Chrome 65, `autocomplete="new-password"` does the exact opposite of what I want. It doesn't show the "would you like to update your saved password..." dialog... it just silently updates my stored password. Worse than useless - dangerous! >:(

Comment: if this is not possible in many modern browsers, is it possible to change the password string just before the browser is going to save it?

Comment: @scipsycho That would probably work, but why would you want to handicap a security feature of the browser?

Comment: @4castle you are right about that. Although, I have seen some sites do this (like my router login), what I am trying to understand here, is how a website is able to fool the browser about the password it's about to save. After, all the web browser sends that HTTPS POST message through the port which also contains the password?

Comment: This _would_ be a good answer *except* that it is usually a trivial matter to view passwords in plaintext saved in a browser. Have all modern browsers require a password to unlock the saved passwords, AND save the passwords with encryption of reasonable strength, THEN you can think about letting the browser save the password for you.

Comment: @UncaAlby Well yes, the user should only login to their password manager if they're on a trusted device. The user can disable their password manager if they want, or it can be enforced by a group policy on the operating system to disable the password manager.

Comment: @4castle you are correct, however, even a trusted device can find its way into the wrong hands. If your laptop and lost or stolen, or your home office broken into, your passwords are as good as stolen unless properly encrypted. The proper behavior of a Password Manager *should be* to always encrypt the saved passwords and always require a specific password to unlock them. If Modern Browsers are going to take on the duties of a Password Manager, that's what they need to do. That isn't the case today, so millions of passwords are at greater risk.

Comment: @UncaAlby On Windows at least, the password manager in the major browsers use your Windows login password to encrypt the data. So the thief would need to also be logged in to your device in order to steal any passwords.

Comment: @4castle There are situations where you want to avoid the password manager to pop up, for example, if the password is used as confirmation for sensitive settings. In these cases, the password manager automatically tries to "update" the password (by suggesting to save it), usually just picking any input information above the password field - causing wrong suggestions in general.

Comment: The semantics over whether this is a good thing to force at completely pointless when you're developing and admin interface that supports setting the password field! Do you think it's safer to force the browser to let an admin save every password for every user they create in their browser!?! Every time I read that "net gain" comment I die a little inside.

Comment: I Disagree with taking the power away from the developer regarding this feature. As with most features, the browser needs to be application agnostic, and all features should be "opt-in", like hopefully the 'save password' dialog. one day

Comment: I agree it's _generally_ a bad idea to discourage password managers for the reasons MSDN outlined.  However, there are use-cases that justify disabling that functionality.  I'm working on a site that, for various reasons, is often accessed on public/shared computers (over which we have no control).  Credentials mistakenly stored on that machine allow subsequent visitors to impersonate our staff.  We'd love to instruct the browser to not store credentials when we detect a shared workstation.

Comment: Just to add to the list, pin codes. Additional layers of security. The audacity of browser to think that they know better than every use case by every web browser. It's 1999-Microsoft all over again, and much worse.

Comment: Password managers are not the best option, the only reason they are recommended so much by "experts" is that they want to hold your passwords, and they invested money in shifting the public's opinion towards this practice. The best option still remains to create a system internal to your mind, where you can "calculate" a certain website's password in your mind, by mixing rare or unrelated words that you always use, with certain characteristics of the website such as its name or accent color and so on.

Comment: @Sasino It sounds like you would prefer an offline password manager, like KeePass.

Answer (score 29):

Here is a pure **HTML/CSS** solution for **Chrome** tested in **version 65.0.3325.162 (official build) (64-bit)**.

Set the input `type="text"` and use **CSS** `text-security:disc` to mimic `type="password"`.

```
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="text" name="password" style="text-security:disc; -webkit-text-security:disc;" autocomplete="off">
```

- Note: Works in **Firefox** but **CSS** `moz-text-security` is
  Deprecated/Removed. To fix this create a **CSS** `font-face` made only of
  dots and use `font-family: 'dotsfont';`.

  > Source:
  > [Get input type=text to look like type=password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17769429/get-input-type-text-to-look-like-type-password#answer-17770817)

The Source above contains a link to a work-around for **CSS** `moz-text-security` and `-webkit-text-security` property.

> Source: https://github.com/kylewelsby/dotsfont

As far as I have tested this solution works for **Chrome**, **Firefox version 59.0 (64-bit)**, **Internet Explorer version 11.0.9600** as well as the **IE Emulators Internet Explorer 5** and greater.

**Security Edit 2023**: I have added the attribute `autocomplete="off"` to the password input. By setting `autocomplete="off"`, you are instructing the browser not to populate or remember any values for that particular input field.

It's important to note that while most modern browsers respect the `autocomplete="off"` attribute, some browsers may ignore it for security reasons or offer the user the option to override the setting. Additionally, different browsers may interpret the attribute differently, so it's not a foolproof solution.

Comment: This may be a bad idea, given that the password field has some additional security properties – e.g. not being able to copy-paste the text inside it.

Comment: @tXK I agree without you.. but you can copy/paste text inside of a password field with a quick trick e.g While in chrome, right-click on the password field, goto inspect then change type="password" to type="text".

Comment: Copy/paste shouldn't be considered a problem in password fields, as that's the theoretical basis for password managers. Ask Troy Hunt.

Comment: I don't think its a good idea. example If we have auto filer or password manager extension how it recognize password field, there may be some option to find it ..but It not a good lesson for beginners

Comment: This was the only solution that actually worked for me on React  with Chrome.

Comment: DO NOT DO THIS! This disables the special security behavior that the password input fields have.  Browsers and operating systems take extra care when handling password inputs.  On macOS, when you're using a password field Chrome marks it as a "Secure Input" which protects apps that have the normal input monitoring permissions from reading it.

and since the browser thinks its boring text, it might store the value for later autocompleting, but it won't store the value in an extra secure way. Chrome's autofill stores a lot of sure you can find in the `autofill` table in `Web Data` sqlite db

Answer (score 23):

I solved this by adding `autocomplete="one-time-code"` to the password input.

As per [an HTML reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/autocomplete) `autocomplete="one-time-code"` - a one-time code used for verifying user identity. It looks like the best fit for this.

Comment: Strange, mdn is suggesting [`new-password`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#preventing_autofilling_with_autocompletenew-password), but neither does work for me in FF.

Comment: This works in so far, as the password is not automatically put into the input field. However, Firefox asks to store the password on submitting the form.

Comment: "one-time-code" doesn't work in Firefox

Answer (score 12):

You should be able to make a fake hidden password box to prevent it.

```html
<form>
  <div style="display:none">
    <input type="password" tabindex="-1"/>
  </div>
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what about <input type="hidden">?

Comment: In browser firefox 84.0b5 (64-bit) version it does not work.

Answer (score 7):

By default, there is not any proper answer to disable saving a password in your browser. But luckily there is a way around and it works in almost all the browsers.

To achieve this, add a ***dummy input*** just before the actual input with autocomplete="off" and some custom styling to hide it and providing tabIndex.

Some browsers' (Chrome) autocomplete will fill in the first password input it finds, and the input before that, so with this trick it will only fill in an invisible input that doesn't matter.

```
          <div className="password-input">
            <input
              type="password"
              id="prevent_autofill"
              autoComplete="off"
              style={{
                opacity: '0',
                position: 'absolute',
                height: '0',
                width: '0',
                padding: '0',
                margin: '0'
              }}
              tabIndex="-2"
            />
            <input
              type="password"
              autoComplete="off"
              className="password-input-box"
              placeholder="Password"
              onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'password')}
            />
          </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

At the time this was posted, neither of the previous answers worked for me.

This approach uses a visible password field to capture the password from the user and a hidden password field to pass the password to the server. The visible password field is blanked before the form is submitted, but not with a form `submit` event handler (see explanation on the next paragraph). This approach transfers the visible password field value to the hidden password field as soon as possible (without unnecessary overhead) and then wipes out the visible password field. If the user tabs back into the visible password field, the value is restored. It uses the placeholder to display ●●● after the field was wiped out.

I tried clearing the visible password field on the form `onsubmit` event, but the browser seems to be inspecting the values before the event handler and prompts the user to save the password. Actually, if the `alert` at the end of `passwordchange` is uncommented, the browser still prompts to save the password.

```js
function formsubmit(e) {
  document.getElementById('form_password').setAttribute('placeholder', 'password');
}

function userinputfocus(e) {
  //Just to make the browser mark the username field as required
  // like the password field does.
  e.target.value = e.target.value;
}

function passwordfocus(e) {
  e.target.setAttribute('placeholder', 'password');
  e.target.setAttribute('required', 'required');
  e.target.value = document.getElementById('password').value;
}

function passwordkeydown(e) {
  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
    passwordchange(e.target);
  }
}

function passwordblur(e) {
  passwordchange(e.target);

  if (document.getElementById('password').value !== '') {
    var placeholder = '';
      
    for (i = 0; i < document.getElementById('password').value.length; i++) {
      placeholder = placeholder + '●';
    }
      
    document.getElementById('form_password').setAttribute('placeholder', placeholder);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('form_password').setAttribute('placeholder', 'password');
  }
}

function passwordchange(password) {
  if (password.getAttribute('placeholder') === 'password') {
    if (password.value === '') {
      password.setAttribute('required', 'required');
    } else {
      password.removeAttribute('required');
      var placeholder = '';

      for (i = 0; i < password.value.length; i++) {
        placeholder = placeholder + '●';
      }
    }

    document.getElementById('password').value = password.value;
    password.value = '';

    //This alert will make the browser prompt for a password save
    //alert(e.type);
  }
}
```

```css
#form_password:not([placeholder='password'])::placeholder {
  color: red; /*change to black*/
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="formsubmit(event)" action="/action_page.php">
<input type="hidden" id="password" name="password" />

<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required
  autocomplete="off" placeholder="username"
  onfocus="userinputfocus(event)" />
<input type="password" id="form_password" name="form_password" required
  autocomplete="off" placeholder="password"
  onfocus="passwordfocus(event)"
  onkeydown="passwordkeydown(event)"
  onblur="passwordblur(event)"/>
<br />
<input type="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tested the many solutions and finally I came with this solution.

#### HTML Code

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" placeholder="UserName" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="text" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"/>
```

#### CSS Code

```
#Password {
    text-security: disc;
    -webkit-text-security: disc;
    -moz-text-security: disc;
}
```

#### JavaScript Code

```
window.onload = function () {
    init();
}

function init() {
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")["Password"];
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(x);
    console.log(style);

    if (style.webkitTextSecurity) {
        // Do nothing
    } else {
        x.setAttribute("type", "password");
    }
}
```

Comment: Beware that this is not supported by many browsers. These will just display the entered passwords in clear text.

Comment: @JPortillo only 2 browsers are not supported: Firefox and Internet Exploder

Answer (score 1):

```
< input type="password" style='pointer-event: none' onInput= (e) => handleInput(e) />
```

```js
function handleInput(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.target.setAttribute('readonly', true);
  setTimeout(() => {
    e.target.focus();
    e.target.removeAttribute('readonly');
  });
}
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order.

Answer (score 1):

I'm making a PWA using React. (And using Material-UI and Formik on the component in question, so syntax may seem a bit unusual...)

I wanted to stop Chrome from trying to save login credentials (because devices are shared with many users in my situation).

For the input (MUI TextField in my case), I set the **type** to **"text"** rather than "password" in order to get around Chromes detection for the store-credentials-feature. I made **input-mode** as **"numeric"** to get the keypad to pop up as the keyboard, because users will input a PIN for their password.
And then, as others here described, I used **text-security: disc;** and **-webkit-text-security: disc;**
Again, careful of my code's syntax, as it's using React, MUI, etc. (React uses capital letters and no dashes, etc.)

See the parts with the // comment; the rest is just bonus for context.

```
<TextField
            type="text" // this is a hack so Chrome does not offer saved credentials; should be "password" otherwise
            name="pincode"
            placeholder="pin"
            value={values[PIN_FIELD]}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                  <RemoveRedEye
                    color="action"
                    onClick={togglePasswordMask}
                  />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
              inputProps: {
                inputMode: 'numeric', // for number keyboard
                style: {
                  textSecurity: `${passwordIsMasked ? 'disc' : ''} `, // part of hack described above. this disc mimics the password *** appearance
                  WebkitTextSecurity: `${passwordIsMasked ? 'disc' : ''} `, // same hack
                },
              },
            }}
          />
```

As you can see, I have a toggle that lets you hide or show the pin (by clicking the eye icon). A similar function could be added as appropriate / desired.

```
const [passwordIsMasked, setPasswordIsMasked] = useState(true)
const togglePasswordMask = () => {
setPasswordIsMasked((value) => !value)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pure html/css (no js) solution

- For input/type=text, use a textarea
- For password, use a textarea with a circle glyph font (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40982531/146457)

```
<textarea required="required" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Your username"  rows="1" cols="20" wrap="off"></textarea>
<textarea required="required" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" name="password" class="form-control password" placeholder="Your password"  rows="1" cols="20" wrap="off"></textarea>
```

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'password';
  src: url('css/font/password.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('css/font/password.woff') format('woff'),
       url('css/font/password.ttf') format('truetype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

textarea.form-control {
  overflow:hidden;
  resize:none;
  height:34px;
}

textarea.form-control.password:valid {
  font-family: 'password';
}
```

Notes

1. Textarea prevent autofill & password manager trigger
2. wrap=off/overlow=hidden/rows=1 force one-line display
3. the required pseudo css make the placeholder works
4. You'll probably need some "prevent eventKey=13 / submit" thing
5. Works fine under ffox/chrome/iOS

In the end, it end up been a freaking webshit sum of hacks (but it works)

Comment: This has the problem where now the browser+OS isn't aware that this field should be treated as a secure password input.  As a result it can be copy pasted and read by anything with pasteboard access, it can be more easily read by a keyboard monitoring program since it's not treated as secure input, or anything with screen reader/accessibility access can read it, etc.  Actual password fields have many desirable security properties.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible in the latest browsers.

The only way you can do that is to take another hidden password field and use it for your logic after taking value from visible password field while submitting and put dummy string in visible password field.

In this case the browser can store a dummy string instead of the actual password.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following. It may be help you.

For more information, visit *[Input type=password, don't let browser remember the password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468288/input-type-password-dont-let-browser-remember-the-password)*

```js
function setAutoCompleteOFF(tm) {
    if(typeof tm == "undefined") {
        tm = 10;
    }
    try {
        var inputs = $(".auto-complete-off, input[autocomplete=off]");
        setTimeout(function() {
            inputs.each(function() {
                var old_value = $(this).attr("value");
                var thisobj = $(this);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    thisobj.removeClass("auto-complete-off").addClass("auto-complete-off-processed");
                    thisobj.val(old_value);
                }, tm);
             });
         }, tm);
    }
    catch(e){
    }
}

$(function(){
    setAutoCompleteOFF();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="passfld" type="password" autocomplete="off" />
<input type="submit">
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to generate random input names and work with them.

This way, browsers will be presented with the `new` form each time and won't be able to pre-populate the input fields.

<sub>If you provide us with some sample code (do you have a JavaScript [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (SPA) app or some server side rendering) I would be happy to help you in the implementation.</sub>

Comment: this doesn't work - the password manager prompts even if the field has no name or id (on Firefox anyway)

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is ask your users to disable saving the password for your site. This can be done browser wide or origin wide.

Something else you can do is to force the inputs to be empty after the page is loaded (and after the browser auto completed the fields). Put this script at the end of the `<body>` element.

```
userIdInputElement.value = "";
userPasswordInputElement.value = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed this a couple of years ago for a specific situation: Two people who know their network passwords access the same machine at the same time to sign a legal agreement.

You don't want either password saved in that situation because saving a password is a legal issue, not a technical one where both the physical and temporal presence of both individuals is mandatory. Now, I'll agree that this is a rare situation to encounter, but such situations do exist and built-in password managers in web browsers are unhelpful.

My *technical* solution to the above was to swap between `password` and `text` types and make the background color match the text color when the field is a plain text field (thereby continuing to hide the password). Browsers don't ask to save passwords that are stored in plain text fields.

jQuery plugin:

https://github.com/cubiclesoft/php-flexforms-modules/blob/master/password-manager/jquery.stoppasswordmanager.js

Relevant source code from the above link:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.StopPasswordManager = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.addClass('no-print');
        $this.attr('data-background-color', $this.css('background-color'));
        $this.css('background-color', $this.css('color'));
        $this.attr('type', 'text');
        $this.attr('autocomplete', 'off');

        $this.focus(function() {
            $this.attr('type', 'password');
            $this.css('background-color', $this.attr('data-background-color'));
        });

        $this.blur(function() {
            $this.css('background-color', $this.css('color'));
            $this.attr('type', 'text');
            $this[0].selectionStart = $this[0].selectionEnd;
        });

        $this.on('keydown', function(e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13)
            {
                $this.css('background-color', $this.css('color'));
                $this.attr('type', 'text');
                $this[0].selectionStart = $this[0].selectionEnd;
            }
        });
    });
}
}(jQuery));
```

Demo:

https://barebonescms.com/demos/admin_pack/admin.php

Click "Add Entry" in the menu and then scroll to the bottom of the page to "Module: Stop Password Manager".

Comment: For that demo Chrome asks to save the password Version 65.0.3325.146

Comment: Confirmed. Chrome 63 does not seem to have that behavior. Looks like pressing the Enter key in Chrome 64 submits the form BEFORE the blur handler on the element is called and therefore Chrome sees the password field. However, if you click outside of the element first and then submit, Chrome doesn't complain. Seems like a bug in Chrome to me:  Submitting a form should always call all relevant event handlers on the focused element before submitting as there could be validation code that might need to run that would prevent the form from submitting.  Both Firefox and Edge do the right thing here.

Comment: The above bug and one other bug I ran into are fixed.

Comment: That fix works in that it hides the popup, however, there is still a way to see the password.  The user can click on the 'key' icon in the chrome URL bar, and if they know the account password of the Operating System, can view the last known password entered into any password text input.  As far as I know, the form doesn't even have to be submitted.  Refreshing the page before submission is not even enough now.  So my theory is it must be straight up recording keystrokes now into any input type=password, not reading dom elements after the fact.

Comment: So Chrome comes with its own password DOM logger.  Fantastic.  That's just what everyone needed.  Broken-by-design web browser feature is broken.  Firefox and Edge don't have this issue.  Not much can be done except hope that Google will drop the non-feature unless, of course, someone wants to go crazy and emulate a password field entirely in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<form action='/login' class='login-form' autocomplete='off'>
  User:
  <input type='user' name='user-entry'>
  <input type='hidden' name='user'>

  Password:
  <input type='password' name='password-entry'>
  <input type='hidden' name='password'>
</form>
```

Comment: Beware: Not all browsers support the autocomplete attribut!

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation, I populate the password field with some random characters just after the original password is retrieved by the internal JavaScript code, but just before the form submission.

NOTE: The actual password is surely used for the next step by the form. The value is transferred to a hidden field first. See the code example.

That way, when the browser's password manager saves the password, it is not really the password the user had given there. So the user *thinks* the password has been saved, when in fact some random stuff is what got saved. Over time, the user would know that he/she can't trust the password manager to do the right job for that site.

Now this can lead to a bad user experience; I know because the user may feel that the browser has indeed saved the password. But with adequate documentation, the user can be consoled. I feel this is the way one can fully be sure that the actual password entered by the user cannot be picked up by the browser and saved.

```
<form id='frm' action="https://google.com">
    Password: <input type="password" id="pwd" />
    <input type='hidden' id='hiddenpwd' />
    <button onclick='subm()'>Submit this</button>
</form>

<script>
    function subm() {
        var actualpwd = $('#pwd').val();
        $('#hiddenpwd').val(actualpwd);
        // ...Do whatever Ajax, etc. with this actual pwd
        // ...Or assign the value to another hidden field
        $('#pwd').val('globbedygook');
        $('#frm').submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: @AristeidisKaravas Several banking apps on the web, uses this method to ensure that the actual password is never stored -- they fill the password field with arbitrary characters just to confuse the browsers password manager

Answer (score 0):

I would create a session variable and randomize it. Then build the id and name values based on the session variable. Then on login interrogate the session var you created.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['autoMaskPassword'])) {
    $bytes = random_bytes(16);
    $_SESSION['autoMask_password'] = bin2hex($bytes);
}

<input type="password" name="<?=$_SESSION['autoMaskPassword']?>" placeholder="password">
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it by setting the input field as "text", and catching and manipulating the input keys

first activate a function to catch keys

```
yourInputElement.addEventListener('keydown', onInputPassword);
```

the onInputPassword function is like this:
(assuming that you have the "password" variable defined somewhere)

```
onInputPassword( event ) {
  let key = event.key;
  event.preventDefault(); // this is to prevent the key to reach the input field

  if( key == "Enter" ) {
    // here you put a call to the function that will do something with the password
  }
  else if( key == "Backspace" ) {
    if( password ) {
      // remove the last character if any
      yourInputElement.value = yourInputElement.value.slice(0, -1);
      password = password.slice(0, -1);
    }
  }
  else if( (key >= '0' && key <= '9') || (key >= 'A' && key <= 'Z') || (key >= 'a' && key <= 'z') ) {
    // show a fake '*' on input field and store the real password
    yourInputElement.value = yourInputElement.value + "*";
    password += key;
  }
}
```

so all alphanumeric keys will be added to the password, the 'backspace' key will erase one character, the 'enter' key will terminate, and any other keys will be ignored

don't forget to call removeEventListener('keydown', onInputPassword) somewhere at the end

Answer (score -1):

While the previous solutions are very correct, if you absolutely need the feature then you can mimic the situation with custom input using text-field and JavaScript.

For secure usage, you can use any cryptography technique. So this way you will bypass the browser's password saving behavior.

If you want to know more about the idea, we can discuss that on chat. But the gist is discussed in previous answers and you can get the idea.

Answer (score -1):

It is working fine for a password field to prevent to remember its history:

```js
$('#multi_user_timeout_pin').on('input keydown', function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 8 && $(this).val().length == 1) {
    $(this).attr('type', 'text');
    $(this).val('');
  } else {
    if ($(this).val() !== '') {
      $(this).attr('type', 'password');
    } else {
      $(this).attr('type', 'text');
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="multi_user_timeout_pin" name="multi_user_pin" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your PIN here" ng-model="logutUserPin">
```

Answer (score -1):

I just change the type attribute of the field password to hidden before the click event:

```
document.getElementById("password").setAttribute("type", "hidden");
document.getElementById("save").click();
```

Answer (score -1):

The password input box is essentially character replacement.
1.download font https://pan.baidu.com/s/1TnlCRB8cam6KgS6OarXu3w (c23n)
2.

```html
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'htmlpassword';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    src: url(./css/fonts/htmlpassword.woff2) format('woff2');
}
</style>
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="password" style="font-family: &#34;htmlpassword&#34;;">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
<input type="password" placeholder="Enter password" autocomplete="new-password">
```

`autocomplete="new-password"` works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).