# how to prevent browser auto complete in password fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I tried the following ways to turn off the browser autocomplete.

**1**.added `autocomplete="off",autocomplete="false" and autocomplete="new_password`"  to form and input fields

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="cardForm" novalidate>
<div class="row form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Security Code</label>
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="securityCode"   ng-model="add.ccInfo.Securitycode" name="Security" autocomplete="off">
</div>
```

**2**. And also tried with adding hidden input fields in front of password fields
like this

`<input type="hidden" name="Security" >`
`<input type="password" class="form-control" id="securityCode"   ng-
model="add.ccInfo.Securitycode" name="Security" autocomplete="off">`

**3**.and also tried changing type of input field from `text` to `password` on 
getting focus to input field

```
<form autocomplete="off" name="cardForm" novalidate>
<div class="row form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Security Code</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="securityCode" data-ng-focus="add.changeType()" id="securityCode"  ng-model="add.ccInfo.Securitycode" name="Security" autocomplete="false">
</div>
```

and js part

```
add.changeType = function () {
 var el = angular.element(document.querySelector('#securityCode'));
 el.attr("type", "password")
  }
```

its disable auto complete first time loads and if i click in the field it shows a list with saved passwords .how can i avoid that
img here[image]

Comment: As far as I know most passwordmanagers in browser ignore the `autocomplete` keyword. Also I believe it's `new-password` (with a dash instead of an underscore)

Comment: Not possible. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41217255/8861405

Comment: Why would you block browser's autocomplete in the first place? It's so useful. It's like you want to frustrate your users

Comment: @JeremyThille It's a common requirement by non-technical people. Sometimes you can argue all you want and you still have to implement it.

Comment: I see... Makes sense. Stupidity everywhere :/

Comment: @JeremyThille I can imagine turning this feature off on public computers, where the user can save password by accident, and then anyone can view it later (by removing _hidden_ property)

Comment: In a similar vein, I often encounter sites which block pasting into password fields, which just encourages people to create weak, easily remembered/typed passwords. Thank goodness for browser extensions that remove these dumb limitations. And don't even get me started on sites which have a ridiculously low maximum password length.

Comment: Make the name of the input "new-password" as well. Or something random, which the browser can't understand.