# PHP, How can I prevent browser from asking to save password when refreshing/resending login post data WITHOUT USING JAVASCRIPT

Tags: php, passwords, save, reload

I am creating a login system in PHP, but I had a problem where you could log out and then go back in the history and reload the page that processes the login POST data, and it would log you in. I added a hidden input with a random value to prevent logging in by resending the same data, BUT WHEN I RESEND DATA, BROWSER STILL ASKS TO STORE PASSWORD, even though my PHP code recognizes an attempt to sign in through page refresh. If I save the password during the page refresh it is possible to back up to the login page and login with saved password. I want to be able to allow user to save password except during reloading of login data. I don't want to use any JavaScript as it can easily be disabled in browser settings. I think I'm using PRG correctly.

Comment: You can't in modern browsers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a browser from storing password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217019/how-to-prevent-a-browser-from-storing-password)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I want to allow password storage, except when resending form data

Comment: If you redirect the user after they log in (As in, user is on log in page, put in their details and press "login". Then, PHP should handle the login, then _redirect_ the user instead of just loading the page), users shouldn't be able to resend form data, even when going back in the browser.

Comment: What Grumpy says.. Do something like `if($loginSuccess) { header('Location: index.php'); exit(); }`

Comment: Thank you so much @GrumpyCrouton ! I had to rearrange some things to get the header redirect to work before any html got loaded, but it works like a dream.

Comment: @ZacharyRudzik Glad I could help