# Any way to restrict browser popup asking to save password on password field or to make text field with similar behaviour like password?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I always get a popup from browser to save password after successful login to site. I figured out that this is due to type "password" in input tag.

I tried CSS property -webkit-text-security but it does not work for all browsers with all versions.

Comment: If you don’t want to store your passwords in your browser, that is your decision. That doesn’t mean you should make the same decision for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent a browser from storing password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217019/how-to-prevent-a-browser-from-storing-password)

Comment: I am developer, and I have to build a site that does not popup for password on login.