# HTML input type text look like password

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, input

I want made login form only use `type="text"`

because, I don't want browser save password/ password save prompt

how can i `type="text"` look like `type="password"`?

### my conditions is

- work in Chrome/Edge
- not use jQuery
- browser do not save `password` or `id`

---

### already try this

1. `autocomplete="off"`
2. add input `type="text"` / `type="password"`
3. `text-security: disc` => not work in edge
4. change input(password=>text) type before login
5. change input(password) data before login
6. change font

Comment: use a font where all the glyphs are bullets - for example https://fontstruct.com/fontstructions/show/1106896/password_dots_2

Comment: why don't you tried in css...???

Comment: @AntonyJack - what would you do in CSS

Comment: @JaromandaX i think this way, but before render bullets font password is showing ..

Comment: have you tried toggling the `readonly` attribute? you might find this solution helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/41362874/7675768

Comment: `but before render bullets font password is showing` - so make sure your font is loaded - not sure how to do that in your case since your code is a mystery

Comment: @DreamTeK How is that?