# How to deal with username and password page items?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2

I am using Apex 18.2.
I have created a report with a form for displaying and entering employees data. Employees can set their own usernames and passwords. My problem is that When I try to create a new employee or edit one that did not have a username and a password set before. The browser populates those two fields with some values. I think with the last entered username and password in the browser. I can not guarantee that users would refuse the browser's offering to save passwords. And if they do not then the next one tries to create a new employee will get the previous password entered. And I think that handling it using JavaScript through emptying the items, for example is not a good idea because the client-side can always be manipulated. I want to control it through the app not the browser. Or maybe better, control the browser through the app and prevent it from saving passwords for the app. Is there a way to do so?

Here is a sample: 
https://apex.oracle.com

```
ws = ESLAM_WS
user = forhelp
pwd = forhelppwd
app = TEST
page = 14 and 15.
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's the browser's offering to save the password you're trying to avoid, there are existing discussions on this 
[How to prevent a browser from storing password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217019/how-to-prevent-a-browser-from-storing-password)

You APEX form seems to behave as expected.

And you should **not** be saving passwords in clear text. [Hash your data](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/storing-passwords-in-the-database-9i).