# Approval compliance with ISO 13485 in web browsers

Tags: browser, password-protection

I am working on a web app that is to be used in an industry with strict compliance requirements, the one I am having trouble with is on signing off something, the user needs to re-input their credentials and it needs to be from the user and not a password manager.

I have tried to implement autocomplete=off and other versions of that as well as changing the type of the password field and it still activates the auto-fill dialogs.

Has anyone managed to overcome this problem at an enterprise scale?

Comment: *"strict compliance requirements"* should include people logging on their own computer sessions and therefore, no form autocompletion shared between sessions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent a browser from storing passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217019/how-to-prevent-a-browser-from-storing-passwords)

Comment: I'm not concerned with the storage but just the insert by the auto-fill popup

Answer (score 0):

Posting here for others that `autocomplete="current-password"` seems to suppress the dialog just in chrome