# How to prevent browser prompt to save the password using primefaces and JSF?

Tags: html, google-chrome, jsf, primefaces

I am using JSF  and i dont know anything about JSF.

I'm a fresher and my requirement is either stop the prompt in the user or save password as encrypted..encrypted passwords are saved in FireFox but in chrome not stored as a encrypted.
My chrome version is 96.

this is my login.xhtml

```
 <div>
   <p:inputText tabindex="1" maxlength="255"  autocomplete="off"
    value="#{login.userName}" styleClass="string text full"
    id="userName"    required="true"  requiredMessage="Invalid User Name/Password ">
                                             
    </p:inputText>

 </div>

        
<h:outputLabel value="#{msg['login.label.password']}"  class="desc"/>
<div>
   <h:inputSecret autocomplete ="off" tabindex="2" maxlength="255" value="#{login.password}"
      styleClass="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext "                                    
      id="password"  required="true" requiredMessage="Invalid User Name/Password">
                      
     </h:inputSecret>
</div>

<p:commandButton 
  id="loginBtn" tabindex="3" global="false" styleClass="button gray small-btn"
  update=":form"           value="#{msg['login.button.loginButton']}"
  action="#{login.verifyUser}"   onclick="submitForm(jQuery('#password').val());"                                                   
   oncomplete="cleartext();jQuery('#ajaxLoading').dialog('destroy');"/>
```

### JS

```
   function cleartext() {
            if (null != document.getElementById("password")) {
                document.getElementById("password").value = "";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Not JSF related. JSF simply renders HTML.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent a browser from storing passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217019/how-to-prevent-a-browser-from-storing-passwords)

Comment: I tried all those too..but some of them works in chrome but nothing is work in FireFox..