# Prevent browsers to save id & password

Tags: javascript, html, forms, browser, any

I don't want my client to store their id and passwords in browsers, because the password field is an OTP.

I tried all the solutions of [Prevent Browsers from storing passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41217019/how-to-prevent-a-browser-from-storing-passwords) but nothing has worked for me

```
autocomplete="off" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"
```

```
autocomplete="new-password"
```

```
autocomplete="one-time-code"
```

These didn't worked.

I also created a hidden password field, it's not auto-filling the actual password field but on click of the password textbox browsers give suggestions which I don't want because it's an OTP.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: The accepted answer is old, have you tried other answers as well?

Comment: @thedemons I tried all answers except the css change

Comment: Maybe you don't need to worry about that. An OTP is only meant to be used once. Once it's used, it should no longer be use-able. So, if it gets saved, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Ouroborus That's an actual issue, when the user is clicking on the password field it's giving suggestion which I don't want.

Comment: An alternative is to simulate an input field without actually using `<input>`. Put in a div, bind to `keypress`, and process the password entry manually. In this way nothing ends up in an input field. Accessibility may be difficult to accomplish this way though.

Comment: What kind of suggestions is it giving? Are you using `type="password"`?

Comment: @Ouroborus yes `type="password"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this link here, it should work for you
[gfg](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-prevent-browser-to-remember-password-in-html/#:%7E:text=Method%201%3A%20One%20of%20the,not%20remembered%20by%20the%20browser.)

#javascript

Comment: Provide the relevant code and explanation in the answer. Link-only answers are not appropriate for Stackoverflow and will eventually be deleted.

Comment: As I mentioned in the Question. These solutions are not working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).